# Asp net mvc - script doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a [project](http://bit.ly/mvc-livrocodigofonte) from a book.

My browser doesn't respond when I click on a login button. I have a file named `Login.cshtml`. It contains:

```
<a id="botao-entrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">
    Entrar
</a>
(...)
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Login.Home.js")"></script>
```

This is my Login.Home.js file code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#status").hide();
$("#botao-entrar").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Usuarios/AutenticacaoDeUsuario",
        data: { Login: $("#txtLogin").val(), Senha: $("#txtSenha").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#status").html("Estamos autenticando o usuário. Só um instante...");
            $("#status").show();
        },
        success: function (dados) {
            if (dados.OK) {
                $("#status").html(dados.Mensagem)
                setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/Home/Index" }, 5000);
                $("#status").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#status").html(dados.Mensagem);
                $("#status").show();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#status").html(dados.Mensagem);
            $("#status").show()
        }
    });
});
});
```

When I click on `botao-entrar`, after typing in the login and password  nothing happens. Chrome shows these messages on console tab without clicking:

[browser message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek4pK.jpg)

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and jQuery scripts (`v2.1.3`) are in my solution in the 'scripts' folder, exactly as book says for me to do.

What are the reasons the login button mightn't be working?

Comment: Those browser errors are telling you jQuery didn't load (404). Check that the path to jQuery is correct.

Comment: You state jQuery **v2.1.3** in your project but your code is trying to load **v2.0.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simply a **jQuery** error. Check did you include the same **jQuery** **version** as you have in your project? or check that the path  you have defined  for **jQuery** is correct?